# How to store date into parse database(iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, parse-platform

I'm trying to insert date and time from two separate textfield into parse.com database, I manage to combined them into one NSString but when creating a NSDate to be stored into the database it came out as nil.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS'Z'"];
NSString *dateTime = ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@T%@",jobDateTF.text,jobTimeTF.text]);
NSDate *dateNTime = [formatter dateFromString:dateTime];
```

And for passing into the database,

```
advanceBooking[@"jobDate"] = dateNTime;
```

Forgive me for any poor formatting, new to stackoverflow

Comment: What's the string you put into the date formatter?

Comment: dateTime, which I combined from my date textfield jobDateTF.text and my time textfield jobTimeTF.text

Comment: Please post an example string, like '2015-11-12 13:24:33.234'

Comment: This what I get from the combined string,10-12-2015T14:38

Comment: That's clearly not the format you specified.

Comment: NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm "];    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"]; This was the format for the individual date and time so it gets combined and shown like this, the new formatter that I specify above, came out nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DateFormatter` specifies year-month-day before the time, but your time string does not contain year, month and day - so the `dateNTime` is probably `nil`.
Have a look at `NSDateComponents` for your date construction.

**EDIT**:
With the new information from your comment:

When you want to get a date from a string, you have to specify the EXACT format - your format string said the date part should look like '2015-12-10', but your string said '10-12-2015'. How should the date formatter know what to do with your string? Please read up on `NSDateFormatter` and the possible format strings, there is also lots of info on that here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Also, the unicode page about date formatting is useful here : http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Exactly the problem, when I switch it to EXACT format it works and able to store into the database, had to add in another string that is the exact format to identify what I'm missing and solves it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *date = [datePicker date];

// format the NSDate to a NSString
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"cccc,MMM d,hh:mm aa"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

// save to Parse
PFObject *addValues= [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"your-class"];
[addValues setObject: dateString forKey:@"your-key"];
[addValues saveInBackground];
```